# Hibernate - Error at child level does not rollback parent insertion into database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Ok so I have a one to many relationship between user and account and one to one between account and account_details. When an error occurs during the insert of an user at the level of account_details the account does not get inserted but a record for user does. Similarly if the error occurs at the level of the account a user account is inserted. EntityManager is supposed to handle rollbacks for the transactions but it is not the case.
Strangely when I update a user account and add accounts to it, a failure at the level of the added accounts rolls back any updates to the user model.

persistence xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="userPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
    <class>com.urbanbuz.model.User</class>
    <class>com.urbanbuz.model.Account</class>
    <class>com.urbanbuz.model.AccountDetails</class>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

UserDAO:

```
@Repository("userDao")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class UserDAO {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

public void insert(User user) {
    entityManager.persist(user);
}

public void update(User user) {
    entityManager.merge(user);
}
}
```

Calling the method to insert user:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
private UserDAO userDAO;

public UserDAO getUserDao() {
    return userDAO;
}

@Autowired
public void setUserDao(UserDAO userDAO) {
    this.userDAO = userDAO;
}

// summary of method, much code was omitted 
public boolean addUser(User user) {
    // add new user and user accounts
    Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<Account>();

    Account a = new Account();  
    a.setUser(user);

    AccountDetails ad = new AccountDetails();
    ad.setAccount(a);

    a.setAccountDetails(ad);

    accounts.add(a);

    user.setAccount(accounts);

    try {
        getUserDao().insert(user);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
}
```

Relationship defined as follows:

at user model level:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
private Set<Account> accounts;
```

at account model level:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id") 
public User getUser() {  
    return user;  
}
```

Comment: This may not be related to the problem, but I have doubt about handling the transaction at the dao level, better do it in the service level, so all the **addUser** method is in the transaction scope.

Comment: @Mooolo thank you for the advice I have changed the implementation as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone faces the same problem - I changed the table type from MyISAM to InnoDB that supports the implemented rollback.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. In my case database was set to use InnoDB but Hibernate, regardless of that, created tables using MyISAM storage engine.

Next line forces hibernate to use InnoDB engine, of course this applies only to newly created tables:

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect

Old ones can be changed using e.g. sql script (`alter table table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;).`